# How to override on swipe from recents list in Android?

Tags: android, service

I have been working on an Android app that has some basic toggles and a Drive Mode feature.  In the Drive Mode, the user may optionally auto reply to incoming notifications and all this works fine.  I even have a persistent notification in the status bar when Drive Mode is started.  One problem is, however, when my app is swiped away from the recents menu in Android, Drive Mode is stopped but the notification is still there.  So my question is, how can I either keep Drive Mode running, or how can I remove the notification.

I know this is probably frowned upon but instead of listing my code here, you may find it at

```
http://github.com/sociallymellow/mango
```

and if you would like to download the apk (or see my other projects) visit

```
http://mellowdev.net
```

I have attempted to make this a service but no luck.  I have also attempted to @Override the onDestroy method with no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: When the user swipes your app from the recents list, the process is killed. You should be able to clean up whatever you need to in `onDestroy()`, but I don't have enough experience with notifications to say offhand whether you can remove them. I don't think keeping your app running is a possibility, though.

Comment: PS Can you post more detail on what you've tried to do in `onDestroy()` (incl. code)? Edit: Checked out some docs, you should be able to call `NotificationManager.cancel(int id)` in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I tried your method and this worked as far as I know.  I also made my app not appear in the recents app page by using android:label="@string/app_name" in the manifest.  I tried this method right before posting my question but it didn't work until I uninstalled my and reinstalled it.  Now works fine.  Thanks for all the help!  Quick too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hidden my app from the recents list to overall fix my problem by adding `android:label="@string/app_name"` to the manifest.  I have also added the following as suggested in a comment.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    nm.cancelAll();
}
```

Thank you all for the help and using both of these together completely solved my problem.  I hope this helps others as well!

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to call super.onDestroy();